# cinnamon-settings and Nemo crash with certain Cinnamon themes' contols on Debian 8

Tags: debian, cinnamon, theme, segmentation-fault, nemo

Installed [mint-x-icons](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mint-x-icons/) and [mint-x-theme](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mint-x-theme/) on a fresh Debian 8 testing running Cinnamon (v2.6.13). All themes options could be set to Mint-X, except for `Controls`.

[image: cinnamon-themes-config]

As soon as it was selected, the `Themes` window crashed and couldn't be opened again, nor `cinnamon-settings` in general. Nemo wouldn't start any longer either and there were graphical oddities at many places. The terminal returned `segmentation fault` for both applications.

Selecting `Troubleshoot...` > `Restore all settings to default` in the panel menu doesn't fix it.

Since the default config editor is gone, how do I revert the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value to revert is `org.cinnamon.desktop.interface.gtk-theme`. It can be set back to `Adwaita`, Debian's Cinnamon default installation value from the terminal with

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface gtk-theme Adwaita
```

or graphically with dconf Editor (`dconf-editor` package) setting the value `Adwaita` under

```
org > cinnamon > desktop > interface > gtk-theme
```